# SSH Dynamic Proxy not working

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, proxy, putty

Everyone,

I am trying to get a dynamic ssh proxy setup so I can do some secure web surfing/testing.

I have tried it on both a Mac (os X 10.6.7) and win7 professional (with putty)

I have 2 linux machines, 1 at the house running CentOS5 and another in the Cloud at AWS running the Bitnami stack for ruby.

The command I am running on my mac is

`ssh -D 1080 root@mylocalCentOSServer`

Connects just fine, I then go to my network settings for my airport and specify the Http and Https Proxy servers to be either 127.0.0.1 or localhost and use the port 1080. I then fire up a web browser (chrome) and try and hit a website, I get an error everytime about "Proxy server sent no data" or "Server dropped connection"

Same thing happens on win7 box with putty, connects fine, I get a shell prompt, but the proxy is just not moving data back and forth.

I must be missing something, please help. Thanks!

p.s. it fails rather I use my localCentOS box from within my own LAN, or from remote, or even the server running at AWS EC2 doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I then go to my network settings for my airport and specify the Http
>   and Https Proxy servers to be either 127.0.0.1 or localhost and use
>   the port 1080.

You must configure it as a SOCKS host, not HTTP Proxy.

Comment: holy crap.... that was the problem....